# Bandwidth limit by IP on Ubuntu UFW NAT

Tags: nat, ubuntu-server, ufw

How can restrict the bandwidth (or perhaps rate of packets) of each IP's traffic going through my Ubuntu Server 10.04 UFW NAT box?

(If this belongs on another SOI site, please move it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [Linux Advanced Routing & Traffic Control HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.qdisc.classful.html).  Too complicated even to summarize here, but well worth it.  I'm not aware of any GUIs for it.

Comment: Great. That link is now 404 :-(

Comment: I updated the link to its new location.